# trim whitespace and &nbsp; from a javascript string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to trim all whitespaces from a string, including `&nbsp;`
I can't seem to achieve this.

The example I have tried was:

```
var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span> &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;';
txt = txt.replace(/(?:^(?:&nbsp;)+)|(?:(?:&nbsp;)+$)/ig,'');
txt = txt.trim(); 
console.log(txt);//should only display 'hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span>'
```

Basically I want the output only to be `hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span>` from the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a element say, `textarea` and assign the value there so that the special characters are decoded and then use `trim()` on that value:

```js
var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span> &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;';
var elem = document.createElement("textarea");
elem.innerHTML = txt;
var txtValue = elem.value;    
txt = txtValue.trim(); 
console.log(txt);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder oh yes. My bad. No jQuery.

Comment: @user2022678 glad to help

Comment: i noticed the '&nbsp;' in the span is actually converted to a whitespace. Is there a way to preserve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `&nbsp;` into hard spaces (U+00A0), then trim:

```js
var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span> &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;';
txt = txt.replace(/&nbsp(?:;?)/ig,'\u00A0');
txt = txt.trim(); 
console.log('"' + txt + '"');//should only display 'hallo'
```

Note that since you had `&nbsp` (without `;`) in there, I made the `;` optional in the regular expression.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your comment; I was editing my original post, so make it a bit more clear. My apologies it these overlapped. Basically I dont't want a full search/replace

Comment: @user2022678 - That's what the code above does, albeit using a hardspace character (U+00A0) instead of the named character entity. But the named entity just encodes the hard character, so...

Comment: Hi; thank you for your input. Is there a way to preserve the &nbsp within the <span> tag? It seems to change into a whitepcae (im using FF for testing)

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;';
txt = txt.replace(/^(?:&nbsp;|\s)+|(?:&nbsp;|\s)+$/ig,'');
console.log(txt);//should only display 'hallo'
```

This'll do the trick, but since the input text contains a `&nbsp` without a semicolon behind it, the output is `"hallo &nbsp; &nbsp"`

For input `'&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;'` the output will be `hallo`

Answer (score 0):

Knowing I'm late to the party, here's my contribution.

Used a [`Non Capturing Group "?:"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) and replaced all of them with an empty string `""`.

**How it works:**

`(?:&nbsp|;|\s+)`

- `?:` non-capturing group, doesn't match everything in a group `()`
- `&nbsp|;|\s+`, `&nbsp` or `;` or
- `\s+` matches unlimited amount of whitespaces.

---

```js
let regex = /(?:&nbsp|;|\s+)/gm;
//let str = `&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;`;
let str = `&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo<span>&nbsp;again</span> &nbsp; &nbsp &nbsp;`;

console.log(str.replace(regex, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    var reg = new RegExp("&nbsp;", "g"); // By RegExp constructor creating regular expression object for matching text with a pattern. and "g" is used from global i.e. apply on every match.
    var result = txt.replace(reg, " ");
    console.log(result.trim());

//2nd Method
var txt = '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  hallo &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;';
var reg = new RegExp("[&nbsp; |' ']", "g"); 
var result = txt.replace(reg, "");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I will be try my best.